# C# Convert generic, inherited type with interface to base type with same interface

Tags: c#, generics

Good day, all.

May I ask you logic why this is not possible?
I'm studying interface & generic now and I think this is possible because Group implements both iPoppable & iPushable. But converting iPoppable to Group is not possible, compiler complains. I'd like to know the logic why this is not possible.

```
interface iPoppable<out T>{T Pop();}
interface iPushable<in T>{void Push(T ag_t);}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        iPoppable<Lion> lions = new Group<Lion>();
        iPoppable<Animal> animals = lions; //Possible
        Group<Lion> lions2 = lions; //Not possible
    }
}

class Animal{}
class Lion:Animal{}

class Group<T>:iPoppable<T>, iPushable<T>
{
    public void Push(T ag_t){}
    public T Pop(){return something;}
}
```

Comment: For starters, your signature in your `Group` clas isn't correct.  Pop should return on object of type `T`, not void.  Also you need to look into working with covariance *and* contravariance.

Comment: Thanks. just corrected. And yes. I was just reading about both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, step by step.

```
iPoppable<Lion> lions = new Group<Lion>();
```

Works, because `Group` implements `iPoppable` and generic parameter `T` is the same.

```
iPoppable<Animal> animals = lions;
```

Works, because both of them are `iPoppable` and `Lion` derives from `Animal`. More formally, this is an example of *covariance*.

> An object that is instantiated with a more derived type argument is assigned to an object instantiated with a less derived type argument. Assignment compatibility is preserved.

by [Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654055.aspx).

```
Group<Lion> lions2 = lions;
```

Does not work, because you assign an interface type to a class type. `iPoppable` just says that `lions` has `Lion Pop();` method, no more! By saying `Group<Lion> lions2 = lions;` you claim that `lions2` is a full-featured `Group` object which will have **all** methods and properties of `Group` class. Which is **not necessarily** true, and that's why compiler complains.

You may help compiler by saying

```
Group<Lion> lions2 = (Group<Lion>)lions;
```

because **you know for a fact** that particularly `lions`, although the type is `iPoppable` is in fact `Group`.

To illustrate what the compiler is afraid of, see the following snippet.

```
interface iPoppable<out T>
{
    T Pop();
}
interface iPushable<in T>
{
    void Push(T ag_t);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Here, we know the truth, so we cast
        iPoppable<bool> group = new Group<bool>();
        Group<bool> group2 = (Group<bool>)group; // Possible

        // What about here? We also convert iPoppable to Group...
        iPoppable<bool> notGroup = new NotGroup<bool>();
        Group<bool> notGroup2 = (Group<bool>)notGroup; // Bad... Compiler was right...

        notGroup2.HelloGroup = true; // HA! Runtime exception.
        // That's what compiler was worrying about.

        // System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of 
        // type 'NotGroup`1[System.Boolean]' to type 'Group`1[System.Boolean]
    }
}

class Group<T> : iPoppable<T>, iPushable<T>
{
    public void Push(T ag_t) { }
    public T Pop() { return default(T); }

    public bool HelloGroup { get; set; }
}

class NotGroup<T> : iPoppable<T>, iPushable<T>
{
    public void Push(T ag_t) { }
    public T Pop() { return default(T); }

    public bool HelloNotGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good day, Dmytro. Thanks for your kind explanation. Indeed, not a syntax,, but I'd like to know the logics! As it was too late to leave a comment, I'm saying thanks first and just started looking at your snippet. If allowed, I'd like to ask you more question in this thread. Have a nice day!

Comment: I checked your snippet and the conclusion I reached is that implicit cast is not allowed even though the interfaces implemented & type are same because explicit cast is allowed in C# specification. This can lead to run time error once different type with same interfaces is cast to the other type. So, is it desired not to do explicit cast in this zoo?

Comment: @Bicycle-ridingDog - I'm glad my answer helped! As for your question, let's define terms right. Implicit cast is NOT a cast, its a type-safe type conversion, which always succeeds and no data may be lost. Example is converting derived type to base type. Explicit cast (which has that syntax with parentheses) MAY fail (+ data lost). It MAY throw an exception if the right hand side is NOT in fact of correct type. The general idea is to avoid explicit cast whenever possible. You can always check type with reflection or catch the exception, but that would be bad practice.

Comment: @Bicycle-ridingDog - [Microsoft docs on this matter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)